# Какой регуляркой извлечь нужную часть строки?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

[Получаю ответ](http://booksearcher.std-221.ist.mospolytech.ru/skbm/response/) на запрос информации о книге:

```
var response=[];//ютф8
var _iddb="1";
var _basequant="2391872";
var _flag45="yes";
response[0]= {
 _size: "1",
 _result_0: {
 _isn: "1606361",
 _id: "SKBM-SZAO-RU/CBS_SZAO/IBIS/117439",
 _level: "Full",
 _iddb: "1",
 _sourceIddb: "1",
 _archive: "false",
 _controlType: "UNDEFINE",
 _status: "NEW",
 _FULLFORM_0: [
"&lt;Автор:&gt;[i class=RP]Кононов, Николай[/i]",
"&lt;Основное заглавие:&gt; Код Дурова",
"&lt;Сведения, относящ. к заглавию:&gt; реальная история ВКонтакте и ее создателя",
"&lt;Ответственность:&gt; Н. Кононов",
"&lt;Место издания:&gt; Москва",
"&lt;Издательство:&gt; [i class=PU]Манн, Иванов и Фербер[/i]",
"&lt;Дата издания:&gt; 2013",
"&lt;Объем:&gt; 188, [19] с.",
"&lt;Аннотация:&gt;Павел Дуров почти не общается с журналистами, но автору этой книги удалось проникнуть внутрь ВКонтакте. Получилось не просто журналистское расследование, а авантюрная история, исследующая феномен сетевого предпринимателя-харизматика и его детища, а заодно и вполне материальное выражение популярности бизнеса соцсети.",
"<isbn:> 978-5-91657-546-0",
""
 ]
 },
 _iddb_0: {
 _number: "1",
 _title: "Сводный каталог"
 }
 };
var test=1;//ютф8
</isbn:>
```

Как извлечь ISBN, то есть в данном случае 978-5-91657-546-0?

Такая регулярка не работает почему-то:

```
preg_match('/<isbn:> (.*?)"/', $htmlDetails, $matches);
```

Comment: `/<isbn:> (\d.*-\d)/` такая работает

Comment: @Илья замените * на +: `'/<isbn:> (.+?)"/'`, теоретически должно сработать, но возможно ещё придётся корректировать шаблон.

Comment: '<isbn:>\s(.*)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо так:

```
'/<isbn:>\s+([\d-]+)/'
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/PQt8Hz/1)

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня ничего не выводится:
`// Записываем содержание ответа (HTTP-клиент Guzzle)
$htmlDetails = $responseDetails->getBody();
preg_match('/<isbn:>\s+([\d-]+)/', $htmlDetails, $matches);
print_r($matches);`

Если вывести только $htmlDetails, скопировать и вставить в переменную, всё ок.

Как исправить?

Comment: С остальными полями работает. Для примера регулярка для извлечения названия книги: `/<Основное заглавие:> (.*?)"/`

Comment: Нашёл ошибку: первоначально ISBN большими буквами.

Comment: Добавьте опцию `i` `'/<isbn:>\s+([\d-]+)/i'`